# Populate a choice field when another choice field changes

Tags: jquery

I have two choice fields. When `choice field A` is equal to `Commercial` then `choice field B` should change to `Staged`.

I've found this hide function and was trying to change it to fit my needs but I'm not good with jQuery.

```
<script src="/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js">
</script><script src="/jquery/SPUtility.js"></script>
<script>

// wait for the window to load
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Get a single select dropdown field
    var assignedToField = SPUtility.GetSPField('AssignedTo');

    // create a function to change the dropdown value based on AssignedTo's value
    var changeField = function() {
        var assignedToFieldValue = assignedToField.GetValue();
        // Change the Contract Shatus field if the selected value is Commercial
        //if(assignedToFieldValue === 'Commercial') {
        if($(this).val() ==== 'Commercial') {
            SPUtility.HideSPField('Contract Status');
        }
        else {
            SPUtility.ShowSPField('Contract Status');
        }
    };

    // run at startup (for edit form)
    showOrHideField();

    // make sure if the user changes the value we handle it
    $(assignedToField.Dropdown).on('change', showOrHideField);
});</script>
```

UPDATED CODE STILL NOT WORKING:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/SPUtility.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() 
{
    // Get a single select dropdown field
    var assignedToField = SPUtility.GetSPField('AssignedTo');

    // create a function to change the dropdown value based on AssignedTo's value 
    var changeField = function() {
        var assignedToFieldValue = assignedToField.GetValue();
        // Change the Contract Shatus field if the selected value is Commercial
        if(assignedToFieldValue === 'Commercial') {
        //if($(this).val() ==== 'Commercial') {
            SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('contractstatus').SetValue('Staged');        }

    };

    // run at startup (for edit form)
    changeField();

    // make sure if the user changes the value we handle it
    $(assignedToField.Dropdown).on('change', changeField);


});</script>
```

Comment: In order for that updated code to work, you need to know the internal name of the field and `contractstatus` (all lowercase) does not look like a typical internal name.  Not to say it isn't, it's just the first thing my eye goes to when looking at your code, especially because in your first example you refer to the field as `Contract Status` (with caps and a space).  That would lead me to think the internal name of the field is `ContractStatus` or `Contract_x0020_Status`.

Comment: To discover the internal name of the field, go to the list settings, and click on the column name as if you were going to edit the column.  At the end of the URL, you will see `&Field=` and then the internal name of the field.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with SPUtility, you can set a field value by:

`SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('ChoiceFieldB').SetValue('Staged');`

Note that if the choice list is a **lookup**, then you have to set the value via the ID of the choice from the **source** list. I.E.

`SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('ChoiceFieldB').SetValue(2);`

Comment: I've updated the code and still cant seem to get it to work...nor does it seem like I can properly ask a question....Heck of a day!

Comment: Don't worry, been there! I have a feeling you should use a double equals in place of a triple equals, to compare only the value, rather than value and type.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using only jQuery -

```
<script src="/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select[title='AssignedTo']").change(function(){
            var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
            if(selected == "Commercial") {
               $("select[title='Contract Status']").val('Staged');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```